# How much territory would a 200-450 kilogram solitary Carnivorous Dinosaur need to survive in a jungle, forest, woodland or similar environment?

Tags: science-fiction, time-travel, dinosaurs, prehistoric-times, island

I’ll give you all some context here.

In, the story that I’m writing, two characters are investigating a scientist who is responsible for unethical practices or is not properly following known procedures. Unfortunately for them instead of just being a scientist with a bit of malpractice the person is a “mad” scientist and has made a time machine which sends the two characters back in time to the Maastrichtian Era. Which is the tail off the Cretaceous period and is thus the age of the dinosaurs.

My two characters are stuck in this time period for at least a year until the time machine properly "fixes itself" and thus have to survive on this "small" island in the Cretaceous period until it does. Nevertheless in an island such as this just surviving would be very difficult. You got to deal with finding food, shelter and most of all predators.

In this case one of the major predators on the island that they have to watch out for is a carnivorous Dinosaur that weighs between 200 - 450 kilograms. I'm not sure what dinosaur to pick yet but I'm assuming something like the Dakotaraptor. The island has everything the two characters need to survive if they were cave men or people from prehistoic times.

However it's still a dangerous island with such a predator. Given this how big should such a creature's territory (and thus the island) should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a ballpark figure by looking at predators of similar size: something like a [tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger#Hunting_and_diet), for example.

> A tigress may have a territory of 20 km2 (7.7 sq mi), while the territories of males are much larger, covering 60 to 100 km2 (23 to 39 sq mi).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that carnivorous dinosaurs mostly had smaller territories (or, more often, higher populations) because their prey was more densly populated, which was also true because vegetation was lusher at the time.  But ... not a scientist.

Comment: Also, the question of how warmblooded dinosaurs are arises.  If they are still pretty much reptilian, they will need less food because maintaining the body temperature is calorie intensive.

Comment: Mary: cue 100 years of paleontological debate.